# Refreshing data via Service

Tags: android, service

I have button in actionbar which after click updates data into data base. I would like to know when Service done single update to populate updated data into adapter and to refresh adapter.

How to achieve this via Service? Or maybe you have better solution for me?

All that update taking place in this function

```
public class SummonerService extends Service {

private Looper mServiceLooper;
private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        DatabaseSummoner db = new DatabaseSummoner(SummonerService.this);
        final List<Summoner> summoners = db.getAllSummoners();
        db.close();

        for (Summoner sm : summoners) {
            String nickEncode = nickEncoder(sm.getSummonerName());
            getSingleSummoner(sm.getServer(), sm.getSummonerName(), nickEncode);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1010); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        stopSelf(msg.arg1);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advice.

Comment: are you aware of `ContentProvider`s?

Comment: You mean..? Don't really know about that.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html and http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/

Comment: I don't really understand how I can use this in my code. My Service is working good, but I need know when single update have been done. Is there any chance to "pass" adapter to Service and then call adapter method notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: see the second link, section `Notifying listeners of dataset changes`

Comment: Oooh, I haven't seen second link

Comment: I think it's too much work and it's too hard to understand for me by now.